# Transmission Bittorrent Client Does Not See Data on Different ZFS Dataset

Tags: symbolic-link, transmission, zfs

Issue: 
Transmission Bittorrent client does not see data on different ZFS dataset.

Environment:
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2 x64
Harddrive 1:
/ - Ext 4 Filesystem
/boot - Ext2
Harddrive 2:
ZFS Pool: zp1  (ashift=12, autoexpand, autoreplace)  mounted:/zp1
ZFS dataset: data (attr=sa, compression=on) mounted:/zp1/data
ZFS dataset: transmission (attr=sa, compression=on) mounted:/zp1/transmission

user: debian-transmission
groups member of: writedata, debian-transmission, read

user: user1
groups: writedata, debian-transmission, read

Example:

- downloaded ubuntu_iso via Transmission bittorrent client to default transmission directory /zp1/transmission and seed without issue

  drwxrwsr-x 5 debian-transmission writedata 5 Feb 13 19:02 transmission
  rwxrwsr-x 5 debian-transmission writedata 5 Feb 13 19:02 ubuntu_iso
- mv ubuntu_iso to /zp1/readaccess/data, and point transmission to path /zp1/readaccess/data for the file location, does not see the file. 
  drwxr-x--- 23 root readaccess 5 Feb 13 19:02 readaccess
  drwxrwsr-x 23 root writedata 5 Feb 13 19:02 data
  rwxrwsr-x 23 root writedata 5 Feb 13 19:02 ubuntu_iso
- mv ubuntu_iso to /temp and point transmission to path /temp, transmission finds file and seeds it without issue

  drwxrwsr-x 23 debian-transmission writedata 5 Feb 13 19:02 temp
  rwxrwsr-x 23 debian-transmission writedata 5 Feb 13 19:02 ubuntu_iso

I can't figure out why transmission can't see files on the one filesystem but can on all others with the same exact permission. Any ideas? Any troubleshooting steps? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Transmission didn't know the user `debian-transmission` was a member of the `read` group. I added `debian-transmission` to that group after starting the transmission daemon.

The user `debian-transmission` could access the directory via `cd` or `ls`. However, the transmission server didn't recognize the group access until I restarted the daemon.